# Textos pendiente de traducir

Tags: discusión, traducciones

Encontre este texto en ingles que dice:

> **This post has been edited 1 times since you began.Your edit can only be saved if it is more through than the currently saved edit**

Aparece la alerta cuando estas editando una pregunta y ya ha sido editada mas de una vez, dejo la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi sugerencia es que puede ser algo así:

> N es el numero de veces que ha sido editada
>
> Esta publicación se ha editado N veces desde que comenzó. Su edición solo se puede guardar si es diferente a la ultima edición.

Comment: Gracias Raul. Para los que tienen acceso a Transifex, la cadena sí se encuentra ahí - >[This post has been \[edited\](*$url$*) *$times$* times…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/134961561?key=595d006d0dc0070ba6be8e8c6e589c30)

Comment: @Rubén, ahí la traduje, una pregunta tal vez para hacer: El tratamiento general de SOes es de "Usted" o de "Tú"?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho debe hacer referencia a la segunda persona del singular, es decir `tú`.

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr, eso creía.